# Android studio doesn't start after fresh install (JAVA_HOME/JDK_HOME solution NOT WORKING)

Tags: android-studio, installation

I uninstalled my older version of android studio (1.4.1) which was working properly (this installation was done a long time ago, and ADK and android studio were installed separately, in fact if I remember correctly I had the ADK installed for use with Eclipse, and I just updated paths in Android Studio to point to that location to use ADK for Android Studio )

I installed `android-studio-bundle-162.4069837-windows.exe` which apparently comes with both IDE and ADK

However after installation, Android Studio just doesn't start up

I have already added both `JDK_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` to environment variables  and the problem is the same

Double clicking on studio.exe studio.exe to get launched (I can see it in the Task Manager for a while) then it just closes (no error message, no IDE splash screen, nothing at all; in fact, if I wasn't looking at the task manager I wouldn't even know if anything was happening)

Computer setup:

Windows 7 service pack 1 32 bit
[image]

Android Studio is installed at
`C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio`

`studio.exe` is in
`C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin`

Contents of `studio.exe.vmoptions`

```
#
# *DO NOT* modify this file directly. If there is a value that you would like to override,
# please add it to your user specific configuration file.
#
# See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration
#
-server
-Xms256m
-Xmx750m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-da
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2.3
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
-Didea.jre.check=true
```

Location of Java:
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25`

Comment: @SnehPandya everything is 32-bits

Comment: For Windows 7 all Android Studio versions since 2022 don't work with symptoms like Java SDK, JAVA_HOME, etc  Don't waste the time - downgrade the version to Android Studio 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

> I installed `android-studio-bundle-162.4069837-windows.exe`

`android-studio-bundle-162.4069837-windows.exe` is for 64-bit OS, whereas, you need to download and install the one with `android-studio-ide-162.4069837-windows32.zip`

As you can see here: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

Meaning that, the one you are stating that the one you downloaded targets to: [Android Studio Windows 64-Bit](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/2.3.3.0/android-studio-bundle-162.4069837-windows.exe) [Top link in the table]

Whereas, you need to download and install the one which is: [Android Studio Windows 32-Bit](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.3.3.0/android-studio-ide-162.4069837-windows32.zip) [4th link from top in the table]

Also, if you look closely, it is explicitly stated that the one you downloaded is 64-Bit & has **-bundle** suffix & **.exe** extension, which also includes **Android SDK**, but the one your PC supports explicitly has **-ide** suffix & **.zip** extension. Included: **No Android SDK, no installer**

Comment: If you click the green Download Android Studio button it downloads the correct installer version, with IDE and SDK. The windows32.zip file is only for the 32 bit IDE

Comment: Thank you but that is not the problem in this case